# Insert a big word embedding vector in latex

Tags: matrices, vector

I am using gensim to get the word embedding vector for the token 'cow'.

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
import gensim.downloader as api

corpus = api.load('text8')
model = Word2Vec(corpus)


print(model['cow'])
```

Here is the print result:

```
[-1.2547063   1.1942102   0.17151938  0.5987412  -0.49579155 -1.2060282
 -0.1634423  -0.16817395 -0.01932111  0.89791673 -0.6204074  -0.6942175
  0.5526197   0.7512524   1.0385613   0.63329834 -0.36372072  0.13436835
  1.5774019   0.6611982   0.03756079 -0.55493605  0.01850715  0.7029431
 -0.31836367 -1.4836626   0.61409605 -0.34402883  0.01940718  0.04913517
  0.22122279 -0.9317553  -0.05954444  0.47895068  0.5322139   0.5262284
 -0.18197684 -0.5717366  -0.9348576   1.8352545  -1.163346    0.06449085
 -0.12519367 -0.17958975 -0.02057225 -0.71246105 -0.9612495   0.0209828
  2.0363474   0.34898216 -0.08456944  0.24616042 -0.47641563 -0.05189624
 -0.51321644  1.1948055  -0.18322913  1.8176553  -0.7698356  -0.05641554
 -0.97348034 -0.11560358 -0.43876162  1.1535367   0.46992347  0.3269939
 -0.114779    0.13100009 -0.30459177 -1.0905075  -0.5375251   0.05887824
  0.58892184 -1.3707904   1.0063274  -0.5675427   0.62443995 -1.1964613
  0.80283827 -0.20880152  0.4350883  -0.5720035   0.29524413 -0.48592576
  0.08546621  0.02609405 -0.0226634   0.03425831 -1.0997567   0.8341457
 -0.7338353   0.92001337  0.23941106 -0.8202021  -0.27842462  0.6777595
  0.6380239  -0.67553854 -0.17544152 -0.8047661 ]
```

And now I want to insert this very big vector to my thesis.
What I tried is this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2 \\
           3 \\
           4 \\
           1 \\
           2 \\
           3 \\
           4 \\
           1 \\
           2 \\
           3 \\
           4 \\
           1 \\
           2 \\
           3 \\
           4 \\
           1 \\
           2 \\
           3 \\
           4 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

I will get this result

[image: my vector]

This is inconvenient, because this vector will go over a few pages :D
Now I wonder if its possible to achieve the same result in latex as with the python print?

Comment: your question isn't very clear, why have you just put single digits in the bmatrix? the data in your matrix seems unrelated to the first part of tee question. you could show exact;y as the python output just putting that block in verbatim, or if you want it in math, just replace the spaces on each line by & and use \\ at the end

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for you comment. I just wanted to save time, so I made just single digits in the bmatrix. I replaced the spaces with & and used \\ at the end as you said and everything is okay now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clarified in a comment but as I'd already made this, one of these:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\advance\textheight4cm
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
[-1.2547063   1.1942102   0.17151938  0.5987412  -0.49579155 -1.2060282
 -0.1634423  -0.16817395 -0.01932111  0.89791673 -0.6204074  -0.6942175
  0.5526197   0.7512524   1.0385613   0.63329834 -0.36372072  0.13436835
  1.5774019   0.6611982   0.03756079 -0.55493605  0.01850715  0.7029431
 -0.31836367 -1.4836626   0.61409605 -0.34402883  0.01940718  0.04913517
  0.22122279 -0.9317553  -0.05954444  0.47895068  0.5322139   0.5262284
 -0.18197684 -0.5717366  -0.9348576   1.8352545  -1.163346    0.06449085
 -0.12519367 -0.17958975 -0.02057225 -0.71246105 -0.9612495   0.0209828
  2.0363474   0.34898216 -0.08456944  0.24616042 -0.47641563 -0.05189624
 -0.51321644  1.1948055  -0.18322913  1.8176553  -0.7698356  -0.05641554
 -0.97348034 -0.11560358 -0.43876162  1.1535367   0.46992347  0.3269939
 -0.114779    0.13100009 -0.30459177 -1.0905075  -0.5375251   0.05887824
  0.58892184 -1.3707904   1.0063274  -0.5675427   0.62443995 -1.1964613
  0.80283827 -0.20880152  0.4350883  -0.5720035   0.29524413 -0.48592576
  0.08546621  0.02609405 -0.0226634   0.03425831 -1.0997567   0.8341457
 -0.7338353   0.92001337  0.23941106 -0.8202021  -0.27842462  0.6777595
  0.6380239  -0.67553854 -0.17544152 -0.8047661 ]
\end{verbatim}


$\def\,{\linebreak[0]\ }
[-1.2547063\, 1.1942102\, 0.17151938\, 0.5987412\, -0.49579155\, -1.2060282\,
 -0.1634423\, -0.16817395\, -0.01932111\, 0.89791673\, -0.6204074\, -0.6942175\,
 0.5526197\, 0.7512524\, 1.0385613\, 0.63329834\, -0.36372072\, 0.13436835\,
 1.5774019\, 0.6611982\, 0.03756079\, -0.55493605\, 0.01850715\, 0.7029431\,
 -0.31836367\, -1.4836626\, 0.61409605\, -0.34402883\, 0.01940718\, 0.04913517\,
 0.22122279\, -0.9317553\, -0.05954444\, 0.47895068\, 0.5322139\, 0.5262284\,
 -0.18197684\, -0.5717366\, -0.9348576\, 1.8352545\, -1.163346\, 0.06449085\,
 -0.12519367\, -0.17958975\, -0.02057225\, -0.71246105\, -0.9612495\, 0.0209828\,
 2.0363474\, 0.34898216\, -0.08456944\, 0.24616042\, -0.47641563\, -0.05189624\,
 -0.51321644\, 1.1948055\, -0.18322913\, 1.8176553\, -0.7698356\, -0.05641554\,
 -0.97348034\, -0.11560358\, -0.43876162\, 1.1535367\, 0.46992347\, 0.3269939\,
 -0.114779\, 0.13100009\, -0.30459177\, -1.0905075\, -0.5375251\, 0.05887824\,
 0.58892184\, -1.3707904\, 1.0063274\, -0.5675427\, 0.62443995\, -1.1964613\,
 0.80283827\, -0.20880152\, 0.4350883\, -0.5720035\, 0.29524413\, -0.48592576\,
 0.08546621\, 0.02609405\, -0.0226634\, 0.03425831\, -1.0997567\, 0.8341457\,
 -0.7338353\, 0.92001337\, 0.23941106\, -0.8202021\, -0.27842462\, 0.6777595\,
 0.6380239\, -0.67553854\, -0.17544152\, -0.8047661 ]$


\[
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1.2547063 & 1.1942102 & 0.17151938 & 0.5987412 & -0.49579155 & -1.2060282 \\
 -0.1634423 & -0.16817395 & -0.01932111 & 0.89791673 & -0.6204074 & -0.6942175 \\
  0.5526197 & 0.7512524 & 1.0385613 & 0.63329834 & -0.36372072 & 0.13436835 \\
  1.5774019 & 0.6611982 & 0.03756079 & -0.55493605 & 0.01850715 & 0.7029431  \\
 -0.31836367 & -1.4836626 & 0.61409605 & -0.34402883 & 0.01940718 & 0.04913517 \\
  0.22122279 & -0.9317553 & -0.05954444 & 0.47895068 & 0.5322139 & 0.5262284 \\
 -0.18197684 & -0.5717366 & -0.9348576 & 1.8352545 & -1.163346 & 0.06449085 \\
 -0.12519367 & -0.17958975 & -0.02057225 & -0.71246105 & -0.9612495 & 0.0209828 \\
  2.0363474 & 0.34898216 & -0.08456944 & 0.24616042 & -0.47641563 & -0.05189624 \\
 -0.51321644 & 1.1948055 & -0.18322913 & 1.8176553 & -0.7698356 & -0.05641554 \\
 -0.97348034 & -0.11560358 & -0.43876162 & 1.1535367 & 0.46992347 & 0.3269939 \\
 -0.114779 & 0.13100009 & -0.30459177 & -1.0905075 & -0.5375251 & 0.05887824 \\
  0.58892184 & -1.3707904 & 1.0063274 & -0.5675427 & 0.62443995 & -1.1964613 \\
  0.80283827 & -0.20880152 & 0.4350883 & -0.5720035 & 0.29524413 & -0.48592576 \\
  0.08546621 & 0.02609405 & -0.0226634 & 0.03425831 & -1.0997567 & 0.8341457 \\
 -0.7338353 & 0.92001337 & 0.23941106 & -0.8202021 & -0.27842462 & 0.6777595 \\
  0.6380239 & -0.67553854 & -0.17544152 & -0.8047661
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```